# Reference to HTML file within HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 HTML pages for my website. They all have large parts that are the same. Is there a way I can link them to another HTML file so I only have to make changes once, just like you can do with JavaScript and CSS?

This is what I mean by the JavaScript and CSS:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" />
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to leverage server-side includes:

In PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

You can use frames (ew) if you need to do this strictly with HTML as well, but I would highly recommend against it!

Answer (score 0):

There are static generators: [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki), [webgen](http://webgen.rubyforge.org/)

(Based on a question I asked a long time ago: [What is the best way to manage duplicate code in static HTML websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088198/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-duplicate-code-in-static-html-websites))